# Magento2.3 - Layout Updates in Child Theme don't work

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

> Please also find updates on the bottom

I want to get rid of all the product compare features on my website.
Unfortunately everything I found so far, doesn't work.
Here's what I tried:

We are using the Infortis Ultimo theme.
To do some customizations I created a sub theme with the following structure:

```
app
└────design
     └──────frontend
            └──Chimney
               └───ultimo
                   └──etc
                   └──Infortis_Ultimo
                   │       └─layout
                   │             default.xml
                   └──Magento_Catalog
                   │       └─layout
                   │             default.xml
                   └──media
                   │       preview.png
                   └──web
                   │  └─css
                   │  └─fonts
                   │  └─images
                   │  └─js
                   │ theme.xml
                   │ registration.php
                   | composer.json
```

The layout changes for removing the compare feature are in:

> app/design/frontend/Chimney/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">                    
    <body>                                                                       
        <!-- Remove compare -->                                                     
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />                
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>           
        <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>  
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>    
        <referenceBlock name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />     
        <referenceBlock name="related.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />       
        <referenceBlock name="upsell.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />        
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />                  
    </body>
</page>
```

The theme is selected in the backend, the general layout is ok so it seems to inherit everything correctly from the Infortis Theme.
But there is no effect on the compare sidebar, buttons etc.

What am I missing?

The other files look like this:

> app/design/frontend/Chimney/ultimo/Infortis_Ultimo/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Infortis\Cgen\Block\AssetWrapper\Combined" name="head.additional.asset-wrapper" template="assets/wrapper/combined.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="asset_name" xsi:type="string">cfg.css</argument>
                    <argument name="asset_id" xsi:type="string">iult</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>    
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Chimney/ultimo/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Chimney Ultimo</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Infortis/ultimo</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

> app/design/frontend/Chimney/ultimo/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/chimney/ultimo',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Update:
>   When I add my Magento_Catalog Folder directly into the parent theme and change back to that theme at least parts of the layout updates work.
>   Why doesn't it work in my theme?
>
> Upadte2:
>   Additionally I just noticed that when I change back to the Magento Luma theme the homepage changes but all the category pages keep the ultimo theme.
>   maybe that's the issue, because when the category pages don't change, of course my layout updates won't work.
>   But why is that?
>   I cleared all caches, deployed all static files and restarted the Varnish service, anything else I might have forgotten?

Comment: First you have to find out which layout or block use for it. if you will be find out then you can remove easily. or you can check some admin settings to disable this products.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not really what I asked for.